# Java single regex as all alphabets or strictly alphanumeric of 6 length

Tags: java, regex

I want to make Java regex for strictly alphanumeric of 6 digits or alphabets of 6 digits. I want these in single regex.
In Stack overflow i found `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\\d]).*` but it did not work for condition of six digits.
I tried by OR inside the regex itself as `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\\d]){6}.*|[A-Z]{6}` but this also didn't worked.

Please suggest what could be a better solution for this kind of regex.

Comment: Perhaps, `^(?:\\d{6}|[a-zA-Z]{6})$`? Not sure what *alphanumeric of 6 digits* means. Maybe you need `^(?:(?=(?:\\D*\\d){6})\\w+|[a-zA-Z]{6})$`. Please share some sample strings.

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]{6}|[0-9]{6}$`

Comment: My guess: [`^(?!\d*$)[^\W_]{6}$`](https://regex101.com/r/kD5zD1/1)

Comment: Valid Strings : APK67D, FGEY8J, JPOVMW.  Invalid Strings : 123456, AGH8GNK, ABHLK.

Comment: `^(?!\d*$)[^\W_]{6}$`  this regex worked for me. Thanks  bobble bubble .

Comment: You're welcome, I posted explanation a bit (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to allow alphanumeric strings of 6 length but disallow digits only.

```
"^(?!\\d*$)[^\\W_]{6}$"
```

- The [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to disallow digits only.
- `[^\W_]` [is a short](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html#obnoxious) for alnum `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

[See demo at regexplanet](http://fiddle.re/hevh8a) (click Java)

Comment: Thanks  bobble bubble .

Answer (score 0):

If is 6 digits or alphabets (Mixed) 
**^([a-zA-Z0-9]{6})$**

If 6 digits or 6 letters (no allow mixed) 
**^([0-9]{6}|[a-zA-Z]{6})$**